# Postrgres not runnig on docker

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, jhipster

I'm trying to up jhipsters postgres.yml but it seems db not running

postrgess.yml

```
services:
  hellohipster-postgresql:
    image: postgres:13.1
    restart: always
    # volumes:
    #     - /D/volume/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=HelloHipster
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
```

docker-compose -f .\src\main\docker\postgresql.yml up

```
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating docker_hellohipster-postgresql_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_hellohipster-postgresql_1
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | ********************************************************************************
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | WARNING: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD has been set to "trust". This will allow
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |          anyone with access to the Postgres port to access your database without
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |          a password, even if POSTGRES_PASSWORD is set. See PostgreSQL
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |          documentation about "trust":
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |          https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |          In Docker's default configuration, this is effectively any other
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |          container on the same system.
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |          It is not recommended to use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust. Replace
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |          it with "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" instead to set a password in
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |          "docker run".
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | ********************************************************************************
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | This user must also own the server process.
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | creating configuration files ... ok
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | running bootstrap script ... ok
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | syncing data to disk ... ok
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | waiting for server to start....2021-02-14 05:57:29.163 UTC [46] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.164 UTC [46] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.168 UTC [47] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-02-14 05:57:28 UTC
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.173 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |  done
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | server started
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | CREATE DATABASE
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.417 UTC [46] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.418 UTC [46] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.422 UTC [46] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 53) exited with exit code 1
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.422 UTC [48] LOG:  shutting down
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | waiting for server to shut down....2021-02-14 05:57:29.430 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is shut down
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |  done
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | server stopped
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
hellohipster-postgresql_1  |
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.544 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.545 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.545 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.546 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
hellohipster-postgresql_1  | 2021-02-14 05:57:29.549 UTC [74] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-02-14 05:57:29 UTC
```

It s not accessable:
on *localhost*;
on *127.0.0.1* ;
on docker-machine ip default
*192.168.99.100*;
on this ip
docker inspect -f "{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" 57293cc4fa40
*172.20.0.2*

Comment: The last line from your log has the database shut down - immediately after the startup so probably it encountered a fatal error.  What does the PostgreSQL server log say?

It is probably in /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_log/ looking at your settings

Comment: I logged to container and there os no log under  this /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_log/(pg_log even doesn't exist) and under this folder root@35924699966d:/var/log/postgresql# ls -l
total 0

Comment: I downgrade jhipster to stable version,before i used beta .And with yml in this version postgres works on ip 192.168.99.100 and with password